# Opening a file dialog without FILE input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen [this](http://www.croppola.com/) website. If you click on the center element, it opens a file dialog so you can upload an image. I know how to open a file dialog by using an `input[type=file]`.

How can I open the same dialog and use its output via jQuery events (for example, a `click` on a `div`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just invokes click on a hidden input;

```
<input id="fileSelector" type="file" style="visibility:hidden"/>
<div id="adiv">Click<div>

...

$(function() {
    $("#adiv").click(function() {
        $("#fileSelector").click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#uploadFile").click(function (e) {
      $(this.find('input[type="file"]').click();
  });
```

where 'uploadFile' may be the div or button which you click and input[type="file"] is the asp.net file upload control whose visibility is set as false